# python manager register issue or just my faulty code

Tags: python, lambda, python-2.x, multiprocessing-manager

I use a python manager to share data between processes. I wanted to break up my code into smaller pieces and created a function 'soFactory' that would take a dictionary of name/object pairs and register the object with the manager under the given name.
In the simple example below I create two lists and register them with the manager. If I use soFactory the manager returns only one of the lists (last one registered) regardless which name I reference.
If I unravel the logic of soFactory I get access to the correct object by referencing their registered names.
I must be missing something obvious but not seeing it.

```
# ------------ prototype for SO question -------
from sys import stderr

def soFactory(dictofSo, manager):
    """shared object factory"""
    for n,t in dictofSo.items():
        print >>stderr, 'created item',n,t
        manager.register(n, callable=lambda: t)

def soRoutine(n, t, manager):
    manager.register(n, callable=lambda: t)

def test_soFactory(useFactory=True):
    """tests the soFactory function"""
    from multiprocessing import managers
    m = managers.BaseManager(address='/var/tmp/tqps-test', authkey='abc123')
    mySOlist = {'L1': [1],'L2':[2]}

    if useFactory:
        soFactory(mySOlist, m)
    else:
        for n, t in mySOlist.items():
            soRoutine(n, t, m)

    m.start()

    m.L1().append('only in L1!')
    print >>stderr, m.L1(), m.L2()
```

---

```
>>> test_soFactory()
created item L2 [2]
created item L1 [1]
[1, 'only in L1!'] [1, 'only in L1!']

>>> test_soFactory(useFactory=False)
[1, 'only in L1!'] [2]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, though counterintuitive it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common python variable scope pitfall, this happens due to the closure which `lambda` created remember the name of variables, but not the object (or the "pointer"). When the `lambda` is called, 
the value of `t` is looked up in the surrounding scope, at that time, the loop has ended, so `t` assigned its final value of `L1`, of course, this depends on the order of return value of `dictofSo.items()`.

You could confirm this by turn on debug log of `multiprocessing`:

```
import logging
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.util.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)
```

`L1` and `L2` have same id:

```
[DEBUG/MainProcess] requesting creation of a shared 'L1' object
[DEBUG/BaseManager-1] 'L1' callable returned object with id '104aef878'
[DEBUG/MainProcess] INCREF '104aef878'
...
[DEBUG/MainProcess] requesting creation of a shared 'L2' object
[DEBUG/BaseManager-1] 'L2' callable returned object with id '104aef878'
```

When you create the `lambda` in the function `soRoutine()`, because a function will create a new local scope, this time `t` could point to the value you expected. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture).